# На что ссылается this находящаяся в grunt.registerMultiTask?

Tags: javascript, grunt

```js
const stylelint = require('stylelint');

module.exports = (grunt) => {
  grunt.initConfig({
    stylelint: {
      files: {
        expand: true,
        src: ['styles/**/*.css', '!styles/reset.css'],
      },
      options: {
        formatter: 'verbose',
        fix: true,
      },
    }
});

  grunt.registerMultiTask('stylelint', function() {
    this.async(); // Какое тут будет значение у this
this.options();// Какое тут будет значение у this
  });
};
```

Я хочу разобраться с grunt.registerMultiTask. Объясните плиз что будет в слове this внутри grunt.registerMultiTask('stylelint', function() { });
?

Comment: а в отладчике вы не можете посмотреть, какое там значение?

Comment: Каким образом??

Comment: да понятия не имею, не имел дела с этим. но если есть код, значит должны быть и средства отладки.

Comment: судя по всему ссылается на `grunt.task.current` ( [тыц](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task), [тыц](https://gruntjs.com/inside-tasks) )

Comment: Значит в this`e данные этого объекта?

        stylelint: {
          files: {
            expand: true,
            src: ['styles/**/*.css', '!styles/reset.css'],
          },
          options: {
            formatter: 'verbose',
            fix: true,
          },
        }